# Bully psychology

Tags: social-psychology, motivation

To be honest, I don't know how bullies' systems work in the US or other western countries, but I think everywhere is similar. I will describe some *pattern* I noticed in bullying and the question is **what psychology knows about the reasons of this specific pattern**. The pattern is when a bully in the street starts assault on a prey, he starts by conversation, usually, by asking something. And sometimes there is no "right answer" and aim is just to beat the prey. Why the bully doesn't start straightforward from beating the prey? Here, I am not talking about the bullies whose aim just to take money or something valuable, but about the bullies who want to beat the prey despite everything.

In answers, I hope to find some research papers where this question is covered.

Comment: Welcome. We have put this question on hold as it is too broad (close reason #1) to be answerable - I suggest to so some research and frame this question in a scientific way (close reason #2) - as of now it is a personal anecdote (close reason #3). We have a [help center covering how to ask questions](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Once properly edited we're happy to re-open it for you.